# Visual Studio Debugger and Cors not working

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an MVC website, and a Web Api application.  I've added Allow-Origin to both web configs.

When I debug both applications and use them, I get:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:50053/api/Test/CreateTest. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:1885' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400.
```

If I publish both applications in IIS8, I don't get this issue.  I've tried manually setting the headers in both the web api and MVC applciations, by overriding the begin-request methods and attaching the header.

When I debug the headers, the allow origin header is there.

Anyone know if this is just a bug in visual studio?  I'm unsure if the issue persists when attaching the debugger to the IIS8 published website.

Edit:  This seems to be an issue with IISExpress.  If I publish both applications in IIS8, then debug them by attachign to a process, I do not get this error.

More info:

1. Testing them by using the built in debugger in visual studio (2 instances of VS, which gets launched in IIS express)
2. yes the MVC application is in chrome.
3. I downloaded a header extension for chrome to show all headers.  The header is there.
4. I configured CORS support by adding the header in the web.config for both web api and mvc.  Specifically this:

> ```
>     <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" /></li>
> ```
>
> As I said before, it works when I use IIS8, and not IISExpress.  Seems to just be a bug with IISExpress.

Comment: How are you exactly testing them? Are you running your MVC application in a browser, and getting that error? Which browser? How do you check that the header is in the request? How did you configure CORS support? It's probable that the CORS configuration has the key to give you the answer of why it's not working. If you don't add some more info, it's nearly impossible to give you an answer.

Comment: Added some more information

Comment: What is exactly what you added in web.config? Did you make any other change to your Web API code to support CORS? I think that you're only allowing CORS access for the server, but not for the Web API itself. Perhaps in IIS you have the same headers in both the app and the Web APi, so no CORS enabling is neccessary.

Comment: Did you mean to add </li> in the code snippet

Comment: Does it work when you replace localhost with a real hostname ?